IntelliJ [Jakarta EE Webservices plugin] Generate Java Code from XML schema using Jaxb produces a "error=206, The filename or extension is too long"
When trying to generate jaxb classes from an xsd in IntelliJ via the menu
Tools >  XML Actions > Generate Java Code from XML schema using JAXB
(provided by the plugin Jakarta EE Webservices (JAX-WS)), I get the following error message :
Cannot run program "C:\Java\tomcat9\jvm\oraclejdk-11.0.18.0.2\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

After some googling, I saw that a common proposed solution is to add in workspace.xml the property :
dynamic.classpath = true
It didn't work (even after reopening the IDE)
I also tried to add -Didea.dynamic.classpath=true (in Help -> Edit Custom VM Options ...) also to no avail.
My conclusion is that the plugin seems to ignore those configs and (hopefully) uses its own.
Is it the case ? If yes, how to configure this plugin ?
Finally, I also tried to copy my jvm directly in the C:/ folder, and to put my xsd also in C:/ and same error ...
Are there really no way to make this plugin work as intended ?

Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after reproducing the issue?

nothing shows in idea.log (no entry for the timestamp where the error occurs)

Could you please share screenshot with generation dialog? Is it reproducible with new sample project?

creating a new sample project helped me solve the problem, Thanks.

The problem seemed to be related to the name of my project directory.
Something like C:\git\com.my.project.identifier .
Even if the xsd is put directly in C:\ with a very short name, it doesn't help, because the plugin maybe still execute its command with a path relative to the project folder.
Creating a new project in C:\git with a much shorter name (e.g. C\git\test) has solved the problem.
Thank you all for your contributions. still a pity to suffer from such a limitation though ...

Awesome! Glad you found the issue and glad I could help

Have you checked your environment variables ? JAVA_HOME needs to be correctly configured.
I know you mentioned moving it to C drive but try shortening the filepath and removing the "-" and see if that works.
